# Firebase not firing a success or unsuccess

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I've followed the instructions exactly, in fact, I even used the code from the Firebase helper in android studio. My issue is as such, nor login or failure to login is occurring with my code! What am I missing?

```
 public void toSubscribe(View v) {
        Log.d("OK", "this part first");


        String strUsername, strPassword;
        strUsername = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.username)).getText().toString();
        strPassword = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.password)).getText().toString();


        if (strUsername.matches("")) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You did not enter a username.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        if (strPassword.matches("")) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You did not enter a password.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }



        mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(strUsername, strPassword)
                .addOnCompleteListener(MainActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        Log.d("TAG", "signInWithEmail:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());

                        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                        // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                        // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Log.w("TAG", "signInWithEmail", task.getException());
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });


    }
```

Not much else to say... I tried using a new JSON file and it still doesn't work. I've Googled tons of stuff but nothing really worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please check the following:

1-you install and add Gson file correctly from firebase console

2- you enable firebase authentication from firebase console

3- you `mAuth` initialized correctly

Comment: 2 and 3 are done.... if #1 means google-services.json i did, otherwise i dont know what you mean.

Comment: @DavidKachlon sorry, my mistake I meant JSON file,

are you sure you add internet  permission to manifest

Comment: Ok, so I fixed it but now I have a new issue...     com.google.firebase.FirebaseNetworkException: A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred. --- I fixed it by adding a repository to the gradle file

Comment: @DavidKachlon check your internet connection  make sure you are online

Comment: @DavidKachlon no problem but check my answer please